# Few sites loads structure first and then contents , Is Ajax behind this ?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Few sites for example [smashingmagazine.com](http://smashingmagazine.com/) , the structure loads first and then the

contents loads into it, the images,text and all,is ajax behind this?

php flush and buffer is good to go with , but what is behind this , can someone throw some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content always loads first. Some parts just load later if they are in external files. Sometimes that causes the content to reflow (e.g. if the content includes images without explicit dimensions set), sometimes it doesn't. The text loads later because it depends on @fonts.

Comment: thnx,if i want to achieve similar flow like smashingmagazine.com. what steps should i follow?